# Uploading Excel Report Data to Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I want to upload my Custom Excel Reports to SQL Server Database.
I designed the tables for reports. uploading the data for 1st month works fine but when I upload the data for second month it will replace the other data in the table. I don't want to replace the date of the first month. For uploading I will use the import export wizard or SSIS. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in the "select source tables and views" page of the wizard click "Edit Mappings":

[image]

Then select "Append rows to destination table"

[image]